# Do I drop this variable from my GLM? The variable is not significant but its interaction with another is

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I'm creating a GLM with quasipoisson distribution and when I do an analysis of deviance one of my variables is not significant, but its interaction with another is. It's my understanding that you include interactions when you expect a relationship between the two, so as one goes up the other will also go up.

Worked.out.vol.hours is Total Time.
AAB...BW is the organisers. 
Sorry about the terrible variable names.

```
Call:
glm(formula = total.debris ~ Beach.Region + Volunteers..n. * 
    worked.out.vol.hour + Survey.Window + AAB...BW, family = quasipoisson, 
    data = ltype.all)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-128.45   -22.71   -10.72     7.98   242.77  

Coefficients:
                                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                         6.298e+00  4.650e-01  13.544  < 2e-16 ***
Beach.RegionNorth East              5.523e-01  1.142e-01   4.838 1.36e-06 ***
Beach.RegionNorth West              7.873e-01  1.233e-01   6.385 1.92e-10 ***
Beach.RegionNorthern Ireland        6.919e-01  1.554e-01   4.452 8.77e-06 ***
Beach.RegionScotland                6.168e-01  1.023e-01   6.030 1.80e-09 ***
Beach.RegionSouth East              7.663e-01  9.997e-02   7.665 2.27e-14 ***
Beach.RegionSouth West              8.261e-01  1.008e-01   8.196 3.38e-16 ***
Beach.RegionWales                   6.714e-01  1.104e-01   6.079 1.33e-09 ***
Volunteers..n.                      1.710e-02  1.235e-03  13.852  < 2e-16 ***
worked.out.vol.hour                 3.579e-03  6.620e-04   5.407 6.83e-08 ***
Survey.Window2000                   3.944e-01  1.893e-01   2.083   0.0373 *  
Survey.Window2001                   1.199e-01  1.851e-01   0.647   0.5174    
Survey.Window2002                   1.804e-01  1.773e-01   1.017   0.3090    
Survey.Window2003                   2.789e-01  1.747e-01   1.596   0.1106    
Survey.Window2004                   1.441e-01  1.738e-01   0.829   0.4069    
Survey.Window2005                   1.008e-01  1.722e-01   0.586   0.5581    
Survey.Window2006                   8.810e-02  1.718e-01   0.513   0.6081    
Survey.Window2007                   7.097e-02  1.726e-01   0.411   0.6809    
AAB...BWAAB Combined               -7.903e-01  6.679e-01  -1.183   0.2368    
AAB...BWAdopt a Beach              -6.070e-01  4.234e-01  -1.434   0.1517    
AAB...BWBeachwatch Only            -4.539e-01  4.227e-01  -1.074   0.2829    
AAB...BWBW Combined                -6.548e-01  4.863e-01  -1.347   0.1782    
Volunteers..n.:worked.out.vol.hour -2.232e-05  1.586e-06 -14.071  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 1238.943)

    Null deviance: 3637808  on 3737  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2952919  on 3715  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

When I run the code to see which variables are significant`anova(actmod1, test="Chisq")`

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: quasipoisson, link: log

Response: total.debris

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


                                       Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
    NULL                                                3737    3637808              
    Beach.Region                        7   141546      3730    3496262 < 2.2e-16 ***
    Volunteers..n.                      1   255212      3729    3241050 < 2.2e-16 ***
    worked.out.vol.hour                 1     1227      3728    3239823 0.3196126    
    Survey.Window                       8    17788      3720    3222035 0.0729141 .  
    AAB...BW                            4    27536      3716    3194499 0.0001807 ***
    Volunteers..n.:worked.out.vol.hour  1   241579      3715    2952919 < 2.2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

worked.out.vol.hours is not significant in the analysis of deviance, but its interaction with Volunteers..n. is, which is expected since the total hours surveyed will naturally increase with more volunteers. I, however want to keep these values separate in the model. How do I go about this issue? Do i just drop the variable altogether? Or do I keep it in because the interaction is significant?

Also, any help with how to succintly report these values would be greatly appreciated since I am quite new to this.

Comment: That does not look like a good model. I suspect you have way too many parameters and should look into fitting a mixed effects model instead. Anyway, off-topic here.

Comment: The data are extremely poor quality, due to it being collected by volunteers, but this is what I've got to deal with. I know that if I get a model that says it explains it near perfectly, then that model is nonsense, because the data itself i know can't show that.

Do I delete worked.out.vol.hour or not?

Comment: Please try to understand my suggestion. If you are not able to do that, you should consult a statistician.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help.